# Find binary gaps in bin number with regex

Tags: php, regex, binary

I want to catch all binary gaps in bin number with regex.
For example if I have 1010010001 I want to get array of these 3 strings: "0", "00", "000" but my regex doesn't use 3-rd "1" for both "101" and "1001" combinations. Here is my regex:

```
/1(0+)1/g
```

How I should modify my regex to get desired result ?

Comment: Why use `1`s at all? [`/0+/`](https://regex101.com/r/K9fXdD/1).

Comment: I want to find all 0-s surrounded with 1

Comment: Then use [`/1(0+)(?=1)/`](https://regex101.com/r/K9fXdD/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure the trailing `1` is not *consumed* by putting it into a positive lookahead:

```
/1(0+)(?=1)/
      ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K9fXdD/2).

A [matching variation](https://regex101.com/r/K9fXdD/3) of the same pattern:

```
/1\K0+(?=1)/
```

Here, `1` matches `1` and this text is omitted with `\K`, then one or more `0`s are matched and `1` presence is checked after the `0`s.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be using split() method to split the binary string using '1', you will get your array of zeros.